# jQuery .cousins() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would ultimately like `.cousins(selector=null, uplimiter=-1, upstart=1,excludeself=true)` but I do not know if this is possible for a plugin. If it is, then I would like those to be passed as a parameter object.

**Update**
This is working code except for the `excludeself` part, which is intended to discard any results that are children of the context.

```
(function($) {
$.fn.cousins = function(selector,uplimit,upstart,excludeself) {
  upstart=upstart||1;
  uplimit=uplimit||-1;
  excludeself=arguments.length<4?true:excludeself;
  if (typeof selector==='object') {
    upstart=(typeof selector.upstart!=='undefined')?selector.upstart:upstart;
    uplimit=(typeof selector.uplimit!=='undefined')?selector.uplimit:uplimit;
    excludeself=(typeof selector.excludeself!=='undefined')?selector.excludeself:excludeself;
    selector=selector.selector;
  }
  var cousins=null;
  var upat=0;
  var at=this;
  var that=this;
  if (at.length===0) {
    console.log('r 1');
    return at;
  }
  var upstart_ct=upstart;
  while(at.length>0&&upstart_ct>0) {
    at=at.parent();upat++;
    console.log(at.attr('id'));
    upstart_ct--;
    if (at.length===0) {
      return at;
    }
  }
  console.log('checkiing...');
  while ((cousins===null||cousins.length===0)&&(upat<uplimit||uplimit==-1)) {
    at.each(function() {
      if (cousins!==null) {
        return false;
      }
      var items = $(this).find(selector);
      console.log('found:'+items.length);
      if (0) {// need to excludeself here
        items=items.filter(function(idx){
          var me=$(this);
          var ps=me.parents();
          if (ps.indexOf(that)) {//?? not going to work huh HALP
          }
        });
      }
      if (items.length!=0) {
        if (cousins===null) {
          console.log('assigning to cousins...');
          cousins=items;
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    if (cousins!==null) {
      console.log('cousins.length'+cousins.length);
    }
    if (cousins) {
      break;
    }
    at=at.parent();upat++;
    console.log('going up...'+upat);
    console.log(at.attr('id'));
    if (at.length===0) {
      cousins=at;
      break;
    }
  }
  return cousins;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

I have never written a jQuery plugin before, so I need help.

Update, here is an example of html:

```
.item
  .item-hdr
    .item-hdr-btn <<source
      .item-body-text-area <<an example of excludeself, do not return this in set
  .item-body
    .item-body-textarea <<target
```

So I would like to say `$('.item-hdr-btn').cousins('.item-body-textarea')` and have it return the first occurance of matches as it crawls up the tree.

Comment: This is of course possible, but the method will be an expensive one. Can you post a HTML example and specify what elements should be selected?

Comment: @undefined I put some example structure up there.

Comment: Lol fair play, your next project should be to create `$('div').brothersGirlfriend();`

Comment: @MarkRobbins Doesn't the first posted code snippet do this?

Comment: @undefined The first snippet was limited to a single `.parent()` call, I want to move up until I get results from `.find()` not `.children()`

Comment: Well (disclaimer: going to mention something i authored), i've written a plugin that finds the next matching element in DOM from a specified start element (next as in if the DOM were printed out on paper, not hierarchically). Might suit your need in this case. http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cousins = function(selector) {
        var $parents = this.parents();
        for (var i = 0; i < $parents.length; i++) {
            var $m = $parents.eq(i).siblings(), $c = $(), j = i;
            while (j !== -1) {
                $c = $m = $m.children();
                j--;
            }
            if ($c.length) {
                if (!selector) return $c;
                else return $c.filter(selector);
            }
        }
        return $();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nJre5/

Edit: I have updated the method so it can accept the desired options, note that there is no need to add `excludeItself` option as it does it by default , if you want to add the original elements to the returned set, based on the version of jQuery that you are using you can call `.addBack()` or `.andSelf()` method on the returned collection.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cousins = function (o) {
        var options = {
            selector: null,
            uplimiter: 0,
            upstart: 0,
        };
        $.extend(options, o);

        var $p = this.parents(), i = o.upstart, l = $p.length - (o.uplimiter + i);

        for (i; i < l; i++) {
            var $m = $parents.eq(i).siblings(), $c = '', j = i;
            while (j !== -1) {
                $c = $m = $m.children();
                j--;
            }
            if ($c.length) {
                if (o.selector) $c = $c.filter(o.selector);
                // Adding the previous collection to the set
                // so the .addBack() and .andSelf() methods can be called
                $c.prevObject = this;
                return $c;
            }
        }

        var _ = $(); _.prevObject = this; return _;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$('selector').cousins({
    selector: 'element',
    upstart: 2,
    uplimiter: 0
}).addBack() // adding the previous selected elements to the collection
  .foo();
```

<sub>Probably the name of the method should be something else, like `elementHunter`, `megaCousins`, `pseudoCousins` or something else.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Well, cousins can be found with:

```
void function($) {
    $.fn.cousins = function(selector) {
        return this.parent().siblings().children(selector);
        //         ^ parent ^ uncles   ^ cousins
    };
}(jQuery);
```

Pruning intermediate results can be done fairly easily.

The node itself is excluded by default, but you can just use `.andSelf()` and you'll have it back.

Comment: Yes, that selects the cousins, originally OP had posted a method that did this, please see the question's edits, OP wants to go up until matching elements are found.

Comment: upvote for 2 reasons: you save my time and I like your "ascii art" sub explanation